# How to have iTerm2 hotkey window slide up and down instead of fading

Tags: iterm

I'm using iTerm2, and my hotkey window used to slide down and then back up. A while ago, the animation changed to having it fade in and out. Is there any way to get it to go back to sliding? I prefer that animation.

Comment: damn only three votes! my life depends on this!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, I had to take that out because it didn't work well on Mac OS 10.10. It is generally unhappy about windows being outside the bounds of the screen and it led to some ugly problems.

Comment: Is this still an issue with Mac OS 10.14? It appears to default to fading in, but sliding off screen when dismissed.

Comment: The logic was revamped in 3.1. It fades if the offscreen frame would intersect a different display, or if the window is not attached to an edge of the screen (e.g., a normal window or a full-screen window, but not a top-of-screen window)