# alternative to TotalTerminal that works with El Capitan

Tags: terminal, software-recommendation, macos

Upgrading to El Capitan broke my dropdown terminal [TotalTerminal](http://totalterminal.binaryage.com/).  Is there an alternative dropdown terminal to replace it that is compatible with El Capitan?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're willing to disable System Integrity Protection to continue using TotalTerminal, [you can do that](http://totalterminal.binaryage.com/#sip). If not, the developer of TotalTerminal says the reason he stopped working on it is that he switched to [iTerm 2](https://iterm2.com/), which he says "offers similar functionality to Visor and comparable features to build-in [sic] Terminal.app." I've never used either, but [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48796/iterm-as-a-slide-out-terminal-from-the-top-of-the-screen) on this site explains how to set up iTerm to work in a similar manner.

Comment: The [responses to switching to iterm2 have seemed pretty negative (example linked)](http://discuss.binaryage.com/t/totalterminal-fails-to-start-in-el-capitan-public-beta/3958/19).

Answer (score 0):

I often use treeterm (http://www.treeterm.com). It has it's own file manager which is tightly synced with the working directory of the terminal (the build-in one or the native terminal of the mac).