# 'Always on top' window on macOS

Tags: macos, high-sierra, desktop, window-manager

I need a way to put any chosen window to be always on top.

For example, if I read a book in iBooks or I'm writing code in Xcode using Sublime Text. I want an application or way to overcome the issue.

I tried Helium and Fluid Browser but they are like web browser it's not I look for. I exactly want any application to be on top always for macOS.

Comment: I used know of a terminal command to do it I’ll try to find again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219116/any-nice-stable-ways-to-keep-a-window-always-on-top-on-the-mac

Comment: @Josh Which of the answer is correspond to my request in that duplicate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [Deskovery3](https://www.neomobili.com/products/deskovery/). It does that and more. (up to and including Catalina)

There's also Afloat (up to Mojave): http://www.perfectlyrandom.org/2016/10/23/always-on-top-in-macos-sierra/

Or AfloatX (for Catalina): https://github.com/jslegendre/AfloatX

Note: these require you to temporarily lower the security settings on your Mac (disabling SIP) during part of the installation/setup.

Alternatively, you might want to investigate the following macOS features: Full Screen, Mission Control, Hot Corners and Spaces which all allow easy and flexible control of application windows.

Comment: by the by, it doesn't work nowadays.

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname what doesn't work? Deskovery3? Alfoat? And what is "nowadays"? Catalina? Mojave?

Comment: deskovery 10.15.3 catalina "toggle float" feature doesn't work. I used it last year in a perfectly valid way.

Comment: Has anyone been able to use the "Toggle Float" feature of Deskovery3 successfully on BigSur?

Comment: @SanjivJivan though sip is disabled, no work

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep SIP enabled you can use BetterTouchTool (https://folivora.ai) it now has an option to keep a window floating. The action is called "Pin/Unpin Focused Window to Float on Top"
It works with most windows, but not with DRMed video content like Netflix. (It basically floats a live video stream of the backgrounded window on top)