# How to stop Gmail going behind Chrome when link clicked?

Tags: macos, focus

I have Gmail open on my Macos laptop screen. Connected is a second monitor, with a Chrome window open. Also on the laptop screen, but behind Gmail is another Chrome window. I click a link in Gmail and it opens it on the second monitor, which is great. But this also brings to the front the Chrome window on the laptop screen, thus hiding Gmail. How do I stop Gmail getting hidden when I click a link in it? (I don't want to close the other Chrome window on the laptop screen beforehand just for this - I simply don't want opening the link to hide Gmail. There must be a way so that Gmail stays on top when the link is clicked?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any nice, stable ways to keep a window 'Always on top' on the Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219116/any-nice-stable-ways-to-keep-a-window-always-on-top-on-the-mac)

Comment: What do you mean with "Gmail open"? Is this an application, or a browser window (and which browser)?

Comment: I've set up a Chrome window as a separately loading app, so that the one Chrome window which has Gmail loaded in it acts like an app on its own and even sits in the dock. But it's not just another of chrome's windows - it acts separately to the rest of the browser as though its own app. If it's easier just replace 'Gmail' in my question with any other app from which you might open links.

Comment: Relying to thinkr: No, and much of that page was incomprehensible to me as I'm not a competent coder.

Comment: Sorry, hope you find an answer. (PS: Use @username to notify the person you're replying to ;) )