# How do I configure a global hotkey for iTerm 2?

Tags: terminal, macos, iterm

I'm a new OSX user, and I've used Linux for the past 1.5 years, and I really can't live without dropdown terminal. So I googled, and came across this question: [iTerm as a slide-out terminal from the top of the screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48796/iterm-as-a-slide-out-terminal-from-the-top-of-the-screen)

However, it doesn't work for me. There's no option whatsoever like that, and there's no updated answers covering this. Is there a way to enable it, as google doesn't really help me with this.

I've included a picture of my keys tab here: [image: http://i.imgur.com/M6G5wCj.png]

It's not in the mappings menu either. I'm not married to iTerm, but TotalTerminal is discontinued. I did install Apptivate but it's not the same as a dropdown terminal.

Comment: What version of iTerm have you got? note that the other question refers to iTerm2  http://iterm2.com not iTerm -this is general usage as iTerm is old

Comment: iTerm 2, sorry I thought it was obvious.

Comment: And the full version number - your screen shot does not match build 2.1 which matches the other question

Comment: Are you super sure it's Iterm 2? I don't think Iterm 2's preferences have ever looked the same as your screenshot.

Comment: Weird. I used "Get Info" from Finder, and it says 3.0.0 on the version part. But it says iTerm 2 on the label...

Comment: It just struck me, the screenshot you posted is from the Profiles section of the preferences. **You need to go to `Preferences > Keys`** not `Preferences > Profiles > Keys`.

Comment: I don't even have `Preferences > Profiles > Keys`, that is the `Preferences > Keys` tab I'm on

Comment: It's hard to tell, as you have cropped some of the preferences window off in the screenshot. To clarify: [This is where you are](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6jmf3.png) **and** [This is where you should be](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1rXvk.png)

Comment: Not really, that's the whole preferences window I got with cmd + i, I don't even have appearance, arrangements & pointer menus.

Comment: Personally I go to the preferences with `cmd+,`, which is the `preferences` shortcut for most mac applications. Could be that `cmd+i` leads somewhere else.

Answer (score 30):

You're in the wrong preferences. That's the Appearance settings, available with ⌘I or the Appearance tab in the app Preferences (⌘,). You should be in iTerm → Preferences (⌘,) to access the app preferences, then select Keys in the toolbar at the top.

Specifically:

[image: Hotkey Setup in iTerm 2]

Answer (score 14):

On updated versions you will see... **Create a Dedicated Hotkey Window...**

[image]

Comment: That’s pretty cool but *this is not the same as the previous option!* The new “Dedicated Hotkey Window” option creates a *new*, dedicated floating window (although this can be configured via its profile). The old option re-focussed the existing iTerm window, if one exists. Unfortunately the new settings UI doesn’t seem to contain this option any more, even though the behaviour still exists (after updating iTerm from a previous version, the previously-configured hotkey continues to function). The new “Show/hide” function, by contrast, only toggles existing windows, it doesn’t open a new one.