# Prevent iTerm2 from opening new terminal from dock

Tags: dock, iterm

I just switched from TotalTerminal to iTerm2, and the feature I used the most was the visor. When I used my shortcut key (option + `), it'd drop a terminal from the top of the screen that i could tuck away with the visor shortcut again. Alternatively, if I clicked the terminal button in the dock, I could pull down the visor (or if I had other terminals open, I could go to those).

Is there a way I can have iTerm2 not open a new terminal when I click on it in the dock, but to just go to the most recent active terminal (which may be the visor)?

I'm running Mac OS Sierra (10.12.5).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found it! I'm using Iterm 3 and found the following setting under "Advanced":
[image]

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I also had to go to keys -> create dedicated hotkey window to make the setting take effect.

Comment: Screenshot is dead. So I just mark as No to "Open a new window when you click dock icon and no windows are already open?" in Preferences > Advanced

Answer (score 2):

As answered [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48796/iterm-as-a-slide-out-terminal-from-the-top-of-the-screen), you can use a shortcut to hide/display open terminals.

However, I don't think you can "restore" a previous session, since when you *close* the iTerm2, it ends the current session.

Comment: I've got the shortcut to do the quake-console type thing. All I want is that when I click the iterm2 icon in the dock (when iterm2 is already running), it doesn't open a new terminal (and ideally shifts focus to the last used terminal/visor).

Comment: So you want to use the dock icon as you use your Hotkey ?

Comment: I have a hotkey already, and that functionality works fine. I just don't want clicking on the iterm2 icon in the dock to open a new terminal, but to open the last used terminal (which may be the visor).

Comment: @Batman It is possible by going to Keys -> Hotkey -> Create A Dedicated Hotkey Window -> On Dock Icon Click -> Show This Hotkey Window