# open iTerm2 as floating popup window on current app instead of in a new window

Tags: terminal, iterm

when I launch iTerm it opens in a new window, I want to open it in front of the current app.
I know I can set a hotkey (https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/48805/424333) that'll show iTerm on the current screen but I want to also open it like that when I launch the app from Raycast or Spotlight. I couldn't find a way to achieve that.

Comment: I read and te-read but stiil don’t  comprehend: “when I launch iTerm it opens in a new window, I want to open it in front of the current app.”. What does it mean?

Comment: like a popup window in front of the current app like chrome browser, VSCode, finder, etc

Comment: Doesn't "Show/hide all windows with a system-wide hotkey" do just that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a preference for this, in Preferences → Appearance, called "Exclude from Dock and ⌘-Tab Application Switcher".  This will open in the "current app" in the sense that it will not have its own dock icon, and will be present in fullscreen apps as well without switching spaces.

[image]

If by "popup" you mean the hotkey / HUD windows, then you need to go to the Profiles tab and choose the "Hotkey Window" and set it as the default profile.

[image]